# How to do batch redirection for commands with options

Tags: batch-file, redirect, scp

I'm trying to run a series of commands that requires the user's password, so I'm asking for the password at the beginning of the script and redirect to the command using `|` (pipe redirection).

In the documentation I found the syntax:

```
set password=secretpassword
echo %password% | command that prompt for password
```

I tried with the scp command to copy one file from the server with the following code:

```
echo %password% | scp myuser@serverip:/home/myuser/myfile ./myfile
```

but didn't work.

But this code works, for some reason:

```
echo %password | %scp myuser@serverip:/home/myuser/myfile ./myfile
```

I didn't understand why, maybe the interpretation of pipe inside %% is different.

The main problem is when I pass options to the command, like to get a folder recursive, it doesn't work. Example:

```
echo %password | %scp -r myuser@serverip:/home/myuser/myfolder ./myfolder
```

I know that there are other better methods like using key pair authentication instead of a password, but I want to understand why it's not working.

Comment: `%password | %` should absolutely _NOT_ be working, and there's almost certainly some character in your password that's making things weird.

Comment: Probably the ! or the @ symbol.. But this is entered by user, there is any way to escape this text?  If I use ```echo %password%``` the ! is missing, but with ```echo !password!``` the ! is there, but the redirection to scp doesn't work

Comment: Not a direct solution for your problem but a hint. `ssh` and it friends should be used with public/private keys NOT with passwords

Comment: `echo %password% | …` echoes the contents of variable `password` followed by a _space_ into the pipe; better use `cmd /D /V /C echo(!password!| …` (given than delayed expansion is disabled in the hosting command interpreter instance)…